# JavaFX get stylesheet variables/background color of a StackPane

Tags: java, css, javafx

I'm loading my scene with an FXMLLoader and in this scene there is a stylesheet "default.css" linked. Now what I need to do is get a variable set in this file in the corresponding controller. I'm able to read out the stylesheet location by using

`playerContainer.getParent().getStylesheets().get(0)`

but I don't want to parse that file all by hand. There needs to be some method to get the color I set in this stylesheet.

default.css:

```
* {
    -fx-background-bright: rgb(100, 100, 100);
    -fx-background: rgb(50, 50, 50);
    -fx-background-dark: rgb(40, 40, 40);
    -fx-background-darkest: rgb(20, 20, 20);
    -fx-accent: #2955e4;
    -fx-accent-bright: #2d60ff;
    -fx-warning: rgb(255, 0, 57);

    -fx-text-medium: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

.app-background {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-background;
}
```

I need the color of .app-background. This is also the background of the playerContainers parent (StackPane), so reading out the background color of this node would work aswell but I dont know how to do that. My last attempt looked like this:

```
    //Set players clear color
    List<CssMetaData<? extends Styleable, ?>> props =  playerContainer.getStyleableParent().getCssMetaData();
    for (CssMetaData prop : props) {
        if (prop.getProperty().equals("-fx-region-background")) {

            List<CssMetaData<? extends Styleable, ?>> bgProps = prop.getSubProperties();
            for (CssMetaData bgProp : bgProps) {
                if (bgProp.getProperty().equals("-fx-background-color")) {


                    Paint p = (Paint) bgProp.getInitialValue(playerContainer.getParent());
                    System.out.println(p);

                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

Which results in

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljavafx.scene.paint.Paint; cannot be cast to class javafx.scene.paint.Paint ([Ljavafx.scene.paint.Paint; and javafx.scene.paint.Paint are in module javafx.graphics of loader 'app')
```

Thanks.

Comment: I suppose you could observe the [`Region#background`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#backgroundProperty) property of the region you're curious about.

Comment: You were absolutely right. I was really confused by that exception, was expecting some bug in fx but it was an array. Anyways it's not holding the correct color propably because it's not the initialValue.
I'll check out the region background property thanks!

Comment: Note that I don't think `CssMetaData#getInitialValue` will return what you want anyway.

Comment: thanks! adding a changelistener to the player containers background property works like a charm! (before I wasn't able to find the background property because I forget to cast back to stackpane in intellij)